# Is there a unified way to get content at a file:// or http:// URI scheme in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, uri

It appears the Net::HTTP library doesn't support loading of local file via file:// . I'd like to configure loading of content from a file or remotely, depending on environment.

Is there a standard Ruby way to access either type the same way, or barring that some succinct code that branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/)?

```
require 'open-uri'

open("/home/me/file.txt") { |f| ... }
open("http://www.google.com") { |f| ... }
```

So to support either "http://" or "file://" in one statement, simply remove the "file://" from the beginning of the uri if it is present (and no need to do any processing for "http://"), like so:

```
uri = ...
open(uri.sub(%r{^file://}, ''))
```

Comment: @Pelle, the examples I posted were just the two different forms for the `open` method -- it doesn't actually directly support the uris. If a "file:///" must be supported, you can simply add code to remove it before passing to open: `open(uri.sub(%r{^file://}, ''))` -- that will correctly work for either "file://" or "http://".

Comment: Hmmm well then I guess the answer to the question is "no" - there is no "unified way to get content at a file:// or http:// URI scheme in Ruby" since even with open-uri you need special handling of file:// urls before passing it to File.open. Your code example needs a call to URI.unescape also.

Comment: @Pelle, sure the answer is "no", but I figured it would be more helpful to give a work-around than just say "no", and apparently the OP agreed with me, because my answer was accepted. And no, there is no encoding done in my example, so URI.unescape is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some experimental code that teaches "open-uri" to handle "file:" URIs:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

module URI

  class File < Generic
    def open(*args, &block)
      ::File.open(self.path, &block)
    end
  end

  @@schemes['FILE'] = File

end
```

Comment: So which part is `OpenURI`? I am assuming it's the `open` method. So the plain `URI` does not have `open` method?

Comment: Note that Ruby 2.6 already has all that https://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/lib/uri/file.rb?view=markup&pathrev=62767

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Lee pointed out, [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) is the way to go here. I've also used it in combination with [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for storing resources associated with models, which makes everything brilliantly simple.

```
require 'open-uri'
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remote_url

  has_attached_file :resource # etc, etc.

  before_validation :get_remote_resource, :if => :remote_url_provided?

  validates_presence_of :remote_url, :if => :remote_url_provided?,
                                     :message => 'is invalid or missing'

  def get_remote_resource
    self.resource = SomeModel.download_remote_resource(self.remote_url)
  end

  def self.download_remote_resource (uri)
    io = open(URI.parse(uri))
    def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
    rescue 
  end
end

# SomeModel.new(:remote_url => 'http://www.google.com/').save
```